# Segmentation fault when using large numbers in native array

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have a problem with this simple array assignment. When I use lower numbers such as 100, 1000, etc. the program works well. But if I use a larger number like 1000000 the program crashes at the following line :

```
int list[listLength];
```

and I don't know why.

The following example works well:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   const long long listLength = 1000;
   int list[listLength];

   return 0;
}
```

But the following example does not work:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    const long long listLength = 1000000;
    int list[listLength];


    return 0;
}
```

using de gdb debugger, i get the following error message just in the assignment:

error line:

```
int list[listLength];
```

error message:

> Signal received: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) For program algorithms,
>   pid 5.252

iam building it on 64 bits pc (for 32 bits target) with mingw32 using c++11.

Why doesn't the second example work?

Comment: You are stepping out of bounds. `list[i+left]`. What happens when `i == listLength - 1`?

Comment: Recursion can eat up the stack quickly. There are many examples on the interwebs of non-recursive bubble sort.

Comment: I've nominated this for re-opening because while it is an example of stack overflow (on Stackoverflow.com which is always nice). The real answer is to unwind the recursion and make this a `do`-`while` loop in about 3 lines of editing.

Comment: @AndyG i fixed what you said to me, but the error persists. Thanks!

Comment: Bubble sort is one of the simplest (and one of the worst) sorting algorithms. Bubble sort is not recursive in any normal implementation.

Comment: OK, i changed the recursion for do while but the problem persists but a bit different, when i use 100000 as listLength all works well but if use 1000000 and debug the application get a segmentation fault in main function at line: int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

Comment: i get the following error line 71:  6704 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) sh "${SHFILE}"

Comment: 100000 probably overflows the stack by the sheer size of the array (nearing 400MB). You will have allocate the array on the heap. However notice you'll require 10 billion iterations!

Comment: As @DanAllen has mentioned, your array is too large for the stack. You need to allocate to the heap: `int *arr = new int[listLength];`. You must do `delete [] arr;` when you are finished with it or you will have a memory leak.

Comment: thanks very much guys! that solve the problem!